# Folder browse dialog not showing folders

Tags: folderbrowserdialog

I have created an application compiled with .NET 3.5.  and used the
FolderBrowserDialog object. When a button is pressed I execute this code:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog ();
fbd.ShowDialog();
```

A Folder dialog is shown but I can't see any folders. The only thing I see
are the buttons OK & Cancel (and create new folder button when the
ShowNewFolderButton properyty is set to true). When I try the exact same
code on a different form everything is working fine.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Check that the thread running your dialog is on an STAThread.  So for example make sure your Main method is marked with the [STAThread] attribute:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Otherwise you can do this (from the Community Content on [FolderBrowserDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(VS.80).aspx)).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the folder in Sta Thread
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The path to the selected folder or (if nothing selected) the empty value</returns>
private static string ChooseFolderHelper()
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var thread = new Thread(obj =>
    {
        var builder = (StringBuilder)obj;
        using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            dialog.Description = "Specify the directory";
            dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                builder.Append(dialog.SelectedPath);
            }
         }
     });

     thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread.Start(result);

     while (thread.IsAlive)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(100);
      }

    return result.ToString();
}
```